# How to set Fill property of a Drawing in cs?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am just wondering if there is a way to set Fill property of a Drawing from cs file? I have a drawingbrush as follows :-

```
if (resourceObject is DrawingBrush)
{
    DrawingBrush iconBrush = resourceObject as DrawingBrush;
    //Is there a way to set fill property in iconBrush.Drawing
    // e.g iconBrush.Drawing.setValue(Fill, "Gray");
    DrawingImage image = new DrawingImage(iconBrush.Drawing);
    resourceObject = image;
}
```

If not, could you suggest me any other approach on doing this? Here is the code for the drawingbrush :-

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="ML_ICON">
<DrawingBrush.Drawing>
  <DrawingGroup>
    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=uiEntityViews:CanvasLinkConnectionPointBaseView}, Path=MeSiteColor}" Geometry="F1 M0,25 L25,50, 50,25 25,0z">
      <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <Pen DashCap="Triangle" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Bevel" MiterLimit="10" StartLineCap="Flat" Thickness="5">
          <Pen.Brush>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF657783" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF2C4758" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Pen.Brush>
          <Pen.DashStyle>
            <DashStyle/>
          </Pen.DashStyle>
        </Pen>
      </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
    </GeometryDrawing>
  </DrawingGroup>
</DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: What type is your `iconBrush.Drawing`? Not every type has a Fill property (for example, `ImageDrawing` uses a bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

The DrawingBrush uses some kind of image to fill the shape it's applied to. Setting a separate Fill value therefore does not make much sense as it would be invisible.

I assume you are using an Image with some kind of transparency so you want the transparent parts to be shown in a certain color?

I can think of two approaches:

1. Have an identical shape behind the one where you use the DrawingBrush using a SolidColorBrush of the color you want.
2. Render a colored Rectangle to a WritableBitmap and then the Image you actually want to use. Then use the WritableBitmap as the source for your DrawingBrush.

In general I would opt for the second one - as it requires drawing the background only once.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of **Brush**es: solid, gradient, image, ...
For a **SolidColorBrush** it takes the color as a parameter in the constructor.

```
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Here is the complete specs [WPF Brushes Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1)